# cold fusion 9: query of query displays no results

Tags: coldfusion

I have a page where I run a pretty large query:

```
<cfquery name="report_details" datasource="#REQUEST.prod#">
select .... from ... where ...
</cfquery>
```

I want to run another query based on result of this query as below, but getting no results:

```
<cfquery name="report_summary" dbtype="query">
select .... from report_details where ....
</cfquery>
```

I ran it successfully directly in database as:

```
select ... <--- summary query
from (
       select ... from ... where ... <----  detail query
     )
where ....
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [Query of Queries](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html) only supports a subset of SQL. Make sure your statement actually works in QoQ (test it with a simple example). Also check if your WHERE values are of the same data type since QoQ can be tricky when it comes to type casting/matching.

Comment: Thanks Alex. The result did not show up in <cfdump>, but once I <cfoutput> a <table>, result set was there. Strange, but I am glad it works now.

Comment: Glad it's working.  If it's not reproducible, I'd chalk it up to a localized issue and delete the thread.